# How to locate where the bug is for "unrecognized selector sent to instance"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

Sometimes my app crashes because of this error log:

```
-[NSNull floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3befd090
```

I didn't call any "`floatValue`", so how can I locate which exact line crash the app?

To reproduce the crash require some specific data from the website I have no control over, so any ideas to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JSON/XML and have a parser(framework) there while parsing it tries to get `floatValue` but the value returned is `null`.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (if necessary all of the method(s) that run when the crash happens).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to add an Exception Breakpoint.

Go to the back point pane and click op de `+` in the left corner. In popup select `Add Exception Breakpoint`.

Just click `Done` in the popup, no you have a breakpoint on any exception thrown by the debugger which will allow you to locate the line where the error is thrown.

Comment: Also, it may be a good idea to change the global exception breakpoint to only show Objective-C exception, otherwise it can show many C exceptions which probably are not an issue (for example with audio libraries).